# char* const args[] definition

Tags: c++, c, linux, constants

I'm having trouble understanding the usage of const here:

```
char* const args[];
```

does that mean args cannot point to a new address? How is it different from:

```
const char* args[];
```

Also I'm trying to traverse through this list and append the values to a string using a single for loop statement:

```
string t_command;
for(char** t= args; (*t) != NULL ; t++ && t_command.append(*t + " ")) {}
```

I'm not doing something right here and I can't figure out what.

Comment: There are approximately infinite questions about what `const` means in C/C++ here on Stack Overflow.  Please use the search facility before posting...

Comment: It means, array of const pointers, pointing to char. You cannot change them. Your loop is wrong.

Comment: There's also [http://cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char%2A+const+args%5B%5D%3B) to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I understand char* const and const char* clearly. The question here has to do with double pointer consts.

Comment: You should read pointers from right to left, in the first it is "constant pointer to a char" and in the second "pointer to a char that is constant"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
char* const args[];
```

`args` is an array. Each element in the array is a pointer to `char`. Those pointers are `const`. You cannot modify the elements of the array to point anywhere else. However, you can modify the `char`s they point at.

```
const char* args[];
```

`args` is still an array. Each element in the array is still a pointer to `char`. However, the pointers are *not* `const`. You can modify the elements of the array to point elsewhere. However, you *cannot* modify the `char`s they point at.

Diagram time:

```
Args:
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │   │   │   │  // In the first version, these pointers are const
└─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┘
  ┃   ┗━┓ ┗━┅ ┗━┅ ┗━┅ ┗━┅
  ▼     ▼
┌───┐ ┌───┐
│ c │ │ c │                // In the second version, these characters are const
└───┘ └───┘
```

Often, when you have a pointer to characters, those characters are part of an array themselves (a C-style string), in which case it looks like this:

```
Args:
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│   │   │   │   │   │   │  // In the first version, these pointers are const
└─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┴─╂─┘
  ┃   ┗━━━━━━━┓   ┗━┅ ┗━┅
  ▼           ▼
┌───┬───┬┄  ┌───┬───┬┄
│ c │ c │   │ c │ c │      // In the second version, these characters are const
└───┴───┴┄  └───┴───┴┄
```

As for traversing through the array, you are attempting to treat the `args` array as null-terminated. That's not how most arrays work. You should iterate using an index into the array.

Also note that you cannot add an array and a string literal together (as in `*t ++ " "`). Convert one side to a `std::string` to make it much easier.

So if `N` is the size of `args`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  t_command.append(std::string(args[i]) + " "))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* const args[];
```

`args` is an array of constant pointers to `char`. The pointers can't be modified, but the things they point to can.

```
const char* args[];
```

`args` is an array of pointers to `const char`. The pointers can be modified, but the things they point to can't.

If you want a pointer to the first element of `char* const args[];`, then its type must be a pointer to a constant pointer:

```
for (char * const * t = args; *t; ++t) {
    t_command.append(*t + " ");
}
```